# Gremlin: Get unique properties of edges leaving from vertex

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have the `id` of a vertex and there are multiple edges leaving from it with the properties: `version`, `status`, `name`. There can be multiple edges with the same `version` and `status` but with a different `name`.

How can I get all the unique `version` and `status` combinations starting from the vertex `id`?

I have tried this:

```
G.V("1").outE()
  .group()
  .by(select("version", "status"))
  .by(select("version", "status"))
```

But it is not returning anything (the result is an empty map).

I have tried this:

```
G.V("1").outE()
  .group()
  .by(values("version", "status"))
  .by(values("version", "status"))
```

and

```
G.V("1").outE()
  .group()
  .by(values("status", "version"))
  .by(values("status", "version"))
```

Both of which are returning a map with one element key 1 value 1.

I was expecting a list of objects with properties like `status`=INACTIVE and `version`=1.

Comment: Need help with my query, stuck with this for long
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73036082/gremlin-simple-path-query-to-get-path-based-on-first-edge-encountered-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the unique pairings you need to convert each edge to the pair you want and then use `dedup()` to get the unique set.

```
g.V("1").outE().map(values('version','status').fold()).dedup()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I am looking for. Now I am getting a map where the key is a list of 2 items (status and version) and the value is the list of edges. What I need is a list of the keys (I am not interested in the edges, only the unique combinations of status and version).

Comment: Perfect! Just to make it clear, I actually needed this: `g.V("1").outE().map(valueMap("version", "status").fold()).dedup().unfold()` so now I have a stream of `Map<key, value>` where `key` is `"version"` or `"status"`.

Comment: then it's just `g.V("1").outE().valueMap('version','status').dedup()` i guess