# Gremlin simple path query, to get path based on first edge encountered property

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

[Sample Graph - actual graph Image See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcWKZ.jpg)

Code to generate Vertex

```css
        graph.addV("organization")
            .property("name", "CITI")
            .property("type", "ORG")
            .property(T.id, "1")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comop1")
            .property("type", "Physical")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("app", "APP1")
            .property(T.id, "4013496")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp2")
            .property("app", "APP2")
            .property("orgName", "ORG")
            .property("type", "System")
            .property(T.id, "2105820")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp3")
            .property("app", "APP2")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "2105830")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp4")
            .property("app", "APP2")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "2100982")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp5")
            .property("app", "APP3")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "4007086")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp6")
            .property("app", "APP3")
            .property(T.id, "4007087")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp7")
            .property("app", "APP3")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "4003585")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("component")
            .property("name", "comp8")
            .property("app", "APP3")
            .property("orgName", "CITI")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "4003586")
            .iterate();
        
        graph.addV("organization")
            .property("name", "BOFA")
            .property("orgName", "BOFA")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "2")
            .iterate();
        graph.addV("organization")
            .property("name", "JPMC")
            .property("orgName", "JPMC")
            .property("type", "Logical")
            .property(T.id, "3")
            .iterate();
```

Code to generate Edges

```css
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge1").from(__.V("1")).to(__.V("4013496")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge2").from(__.V("1")).to(__.V("4013496")).iterate();
        
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge3").from(__.V("4013496")).to(__.V("2105820")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge4").from(__.V("4013496")).to(__.V("2105820")).iterate();

        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge5").from(__.V("2105820")).to(__.V("2105830")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge6").from(__.V("2105820")).to(__.V("2105830")).iterate();

        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge7").from(__.V("2105830")).to(__.V("2100982")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge8").from(__.V("2105830")).to(__.V("2100982")).iterate();

        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge9").from(__.V("2100982")).to(__.V("4007086")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge10").from(__.V("2100982")).to(__.V("4007087")).iterate();

        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge11").from(__.V("4007086")).to(__.V("4003585")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge12").from(__.V("4007087")).to(__.V("4003586")).iterate();

        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS1").property(T.id, "edge13").from(__.V("4003585")).to(__.V("2")).iterate();
        graph.addE("commercialService").property("name", "CS2").property(T.id, "edge14").from(__.V("4003586")).to(__.V("3")).iterate();
```

I have this sample graph, initially 2 edges are coming until they separate out, E1,E2...E14 are the edge ID's and CS1 and CS2 are "name" property of edge.(See Image attached above "Sample Graph")

I am trying to get simple path using the below query

This is a java gremlin query

```java
graph.V("1").
      repeat(outE().otherV().simplePath()).
      until(outE().count().is(0)).
      dedup().
      group().
        by("name").
        by(path()).
      next();
```

This gives me result as Map<Object, Object>, where key as JPMC and BOFA and 2 different path's as map value.

```css
path[v[1], e[edge1][1-commercialService->4013496], v[4013496], e[edge4][4013496-commercialService->2105820], v[2105820], e[edge6][2105820-commercialService->2105830], v[2105830], e[edge7][2105830-commercialService->2100982], v[2100982], e[edge10][2100982-commercialService->4007087], v[4007087], e[edge12][4007087-commercialService->4003586], v[4003586], e[edge14][4003586-commercialService->3], v[3]]
```

But when iterate over this path in Java and try to find the edge property "name", I am getting value as CS1 and CS2. It seems when graph is preparing the path it doesn't matter which edge is used to reach the next node.

Where as I am looking for something where we can get the path grouped by "name" property of the edge, like below

```css
path[v[1], e[edge1][1-commercialService->4013496], v[4013496], e[edge3][4013496-commercialService->2105820], v[2105820], e[edge5][2105820-commercialService->2105830], v[2105830], e[edge7][2105830-commercialService->2100982], v[2100982], e[edge9][2100982-commercialService->4007087], v[4007087], e[edge11][4007087-commercialService->4003586], v[4003586], e[edge13][4003586-commercialService->3], v[2]]
```

2nd Solution tried

```css
graph.V(orgId).repeat(outE().order().by("name").otherV().simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(0)).dedup().path().toList();
```

This time it is always traversing through single Edge, till we reach the common node.
Output :

```css
path[v[1], e[edge1][1-commercialService->4013496], v[4013496], e[edge3][4013496-commercialService->2105820], v[2105820], e[edge5][2105820-commercialService->2105830], v[2105830], e[edge7][2105830-commercialService->2100982], v[2100982], e[edge9][2100982-commercialService->4007086], v[4007086], e[edge11][4007086-commercialService->4003585], v[4003585], e[edge13][4003585-commercialService->2], v[2]]

path[v[1], e[edge1][1-commercialService->4013496], v[4013496], e[edge3][4013496-commercialService->2105820], v[2105820], e[edge5][2105820-commercialService->2105830], v[2105830], e[edge7][2105830-commercialService->2100982], v[2100982], e[edge10][2100982-commercialService->4007087], v[4007087], e[edge12][4007087-commercialService->4003586], v[4003586], e[edge14][4003586-commercialService->3], v[3]]
```

1. There is also a way to pass on the "name" property value in the query itself to follow particular path. But I don't have that value with me to pass on. Instead I am thinking if we can some how use the "name" property from the very first edge we encounter in the path ?
2. Also is there any way to get all the properties of vertex/edge populated when we fetch the path ?

Comment: Tried below query as well graph.V(orgId).repeat(outE().otherV().simplePath()).until(outE().count().is(0)).dedup().path().toList()

Comment: @stephen mallette

Comment: To your second question, while not always a good idea as it returns a lot of data (potentially), you can do `path().by(valueMap())`. For the first question I'm not 100% sure what you want to have the query return. Do you only want to follow edges with the same label?

Comment: As a side note, while graph diagrams are nice, adding the `addV` and `addE` steps that produce the sample graph to the question will help people give you tested answers. See here for an example of creating a sample graph https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72869520/how-to-find-common-vertex-count-and-sort-the-result-in-gremlin

Comment: @KelvinLawrence yes we can use valueMap, but it gives me everything as plain Object, due to which I can not identify whether its an Vertex or Edge. So I moved to other way where we can fetch more details above the vertex or edge

Comment: @KelvinLawrence : Added the code to create Vertex/Edges and yes you are right I want to follow the particular edge based on the "name" property of the Edge, but I can not pass that name in has("name", "CS1 or CS2") as I don't have that information while querying the graph.
I was thinking some thing where I can use the name property from the first edge we encounter for rest of the traversal. So I am still getting 2 paths but each path will use the same edge.

Comment: Thanks for updating with the sample graph - I will take a look.

Comment: Will there only ever be 2 parallel edges maximum between the initial sets of vertices in the graph/diagram staring from `V[1]` ? The path from `V[1]` has quite an aggressive fan out as at each depth there are 2x more possible paths to that spot.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence As of now I believe we could have only 2 parallel edges, don't have clear picture of exact data right now.

Comment: Anyone has any idea how to handle this, still stuck with it

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to get back to this. I have added an answer.

Comment: Checking in to see if this worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially tried using `sack` to write the query but I ran into an unexpected issue. I then decided to use `as` labelling. This resulted with the query below:

```java
g.V('1').
  outE().as('e').
  values('name').as('n').
  select('e').
  inV().
  repeat(
    outE().where(eq('n')).by('name').by().inV()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().from('e').
    by('name').
    by(label)
```

This yields

```
1   path[CS1, component, CS1, component, CS1, component, CS1, component, CS1, component, CS1, component, CS1, organization]
2   path[CS2, component, CS2, component, CS2, component, CS2, component, CS2, component, CS2, component, CS2, organization]
```

You can of course label the path however you wish.

```java
g.V('1').
  outE().as('e').
  values('name').as('n').
  select('e').
  inV().
  repeat(
    outE().where(eq('n')).by('name').by().inV()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().from('e').
    by('name')
```

Which yields:

```
1   path[CS1, comop1, CS1, comp2, CS1, comp3, CS1, comp4, CS1, comp5, CS1, comp7, CS1, BOFA]
2   path[CS2, comop1, CS2, comp2, CS2, comp3, CS2, comp4, CS2, comp6, CS2, comp8, CS2, JPMC]
```

Using this approach, if you want the starting vertex in the `path` result, we have to jiggle things a bit so that the value (edge name) we calculated before the `repeat` starts is not itself part of the `path` result. In the prior examples the `from` step just started the `path` with the first edge. The version below includes the initial vertex.

```java
g.V('1').as('v1').
  outE().values('name').as('n').
  select('v1').as('start').
  repeat(
    outE().where(eq('n')).by('name').by().inV()).
  until(not(out())).
  path().from('start').
    by('name')
```

and we now get:

```
1   path[CITI, CS1, comop1, CS1, comp2, CS1, comp3, CS1, comp4, CS1, comp5, CS1, comp7, CS1, BOFA]
2   path[CITI, CS2, comop1, CS2, comp2, CS2, comp3, CS2, comp4, CS2, comp6, CS2, comp8, CS2, JPMC]
```

Here is a visual representation of the final query. Hopefully this matches your image that we started the discussion with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this works great when we  are only looking at outgoing  edges from a given vertex, is it possible to track bothE(), I tried but getting timeout exception where as I have the until condition specified