# Gremlin query to check if a value exists in the given external map

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop

I would like to traverse the graph until my node property value exist in the set. Set contains id of the nodes and trivial objects.

The query is like:

```
public Map<String,Object> getNodes( Long startNodeID, Set<String, TraversedNode> mySet){
      return g.withSideEffect("x",mySet).V(startNodeID)
             .repeat( ...something )
             .choose( ...something )
             .until( myProperty is found in the given set  )
}
```

I have tried many things in the until part but couldn't get it. Any suggestions to achieve? It maybe related to values and where keywords.

`values("id").where(P.within("x"))` doesn't work

Comment: It will help people to provide you tested answers if you can provide the `addV` and `addE` steps that build a small example graph.  An example of building a sample graph can be found in the answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73433016/gremlin-traverse-path-along-the-same-property/73449813#73449813

Comment: It will further help if, having provided the sample graph, you can also add an example of what the desired result should be. Unfortunately your question is a bit vague and any answer given will require the person answering to guess a bit as to what you are looking for. Is it just the IDs you want to find in the set, as you also mention properties?

Comment: To hopefully advance the discussion, I added an initial answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [air-routes graph](https://github.com/krlawrence/graph/tree/master/sample-data) as sample data, a simple query can be written that looks for IDs within a provided set, as the query progresses. As mentioned in the comments, it is not 100% clear if this is what you are looking for but perhaps it will help with follow on questions.

```java
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('s',[48,54,62,12]).
......1>   V(44).
......2>   repeat(out().simplePath()).
......3>   until(where(within('s')).by(id).by()).
......4>   path().
......5>   limit(5)

==>[v[44],v[8],v[48]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[54]]
==>[v[44],v[8],v[12]]
==>[v[44],v[13],v[12]]
==>[v[44],v[13],v[48]]
```

It may appear that you should just be able to do   `until(hasId(within('s')))`, but in that case `'s'` is treated as the literal string "s" and not a symbol representing the set called `s`. When a predicate is nested inside a `where` step, as in `where(within('s'))`, Gremlin treats that as a special case and will treat `s` as the name of something declared earlier.

Comment: Clear, I will take a look on them. Thanks for the answer